# ConTeXt hyperlinks

Tags: hyperref, context

It used to be possible to add hyperlinks to ConTeXt documents in the style of the LaTeX hyperref package. Minimal **formerly**-working example:

```
\def\href{\dodoubleempty\dohref}
\def\dohref[#1][#2]{\leavevmode
    \pdfstartlink
    attr{/C [1 0 0] /Border [0 0 1]}
    user{/Subtype /Link /A << /Type /Action /S /URI /URI
    (#1) >>}\ifsecondargument #2\else #1\fi\pdfendlink}

\starttext
Here is a \href [http://tex.stackexchange.com] [link] to
my favourite web site.
\stoptext
```

\stoptext

But it doesn't work with recent ConTeXt installations! As far as I can tell, the `\pdfstartlink` and `pdfendlink` commands are *either* silently ignored *or* treated as some sort of switch in/out of a verbatim mode. My guess is that something has changed in luaTeX.

What can I change in my old ConTeXt source files to make them compilable with current ConTeXt? I do know about the esoteric alternatives in [the wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/url) but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to use `useURL`?

Comment: @Aditya I like the coloured-on-screen (but non-printing) borders that the hyperref style used to give me.

Comment: So you want borders around the links, not necessarily the user interface similar to href?

Comment: @Aditya Yes, exactly. It's useful for hyperlinks to be visible on a screen but there's no point in making them visible on a piece of paper. I probably plagiarised the literal pdf stuff from the hyperref package and translated it into a ConTeXtesqe user interface.

Comment: Having `link` as a square-bracketed argument is counter-intuitive.  Typeset material is usually given in curly braces in ConTeXt, e.g. `\goto{link}[anchor]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Metafox's solution explains how to add borders around links. I'll explain why your old macros stopped working.

There has been a change in the [luatex backend](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb37-1/tb115hagen-pdf.pdf). Lot of the `\pdf...` series of commands introduced by pdfTeX are now available as `\pdfextension`. To be backward compatible, macro packages are supposed to define:

```
\protected\def\pdfstartlink             {\pdfextension startlink }
\protected\def\pdfendlink               {\pdfextension endlink\relax}
```

ConTeXt does so in `syst-ini.mkiv`. However, then redefines these to `\relax` in `back-ini.mkiv`. The explanation is:

```
%D Because we do a lot in \LUA\ and don't want interferences, we nil most of the
%D \PDFTEX\ primitives. Of course one can always use the \type {\pdfvariable},
%D \type {\pdfextension} and \type {\pdffeedback} primitives but it will probably
%D have bad side effects.

%D These are no-ops and don't even intercept what comes next. Maybe some day
%D I'll write a parser that maps onto \CONTEXT.
```

That is the reason that your macro is not working. So, you will either have to add

```
\unexpanded\def\pdfstartlink             {\pdfextension startlink }
\unexpanded\def\pdfendlink               {\pdfextension endlink\relax}
```

or use `\pdfextension startlink attr {....} ... \pdfextension endink\relax` in your definition.

Comment: I'm accepting the answer from Aditya because it's splendidly educational and easy to apply to old source files by means of a _sed_ script; but @Metafox gets a vote too, for supplying the orthodox ConTeXt MkIV solution for use hereafter.

Answer (score 11):

You can add borders to references with the `references.border` directive, the default color for the frame is black but you can change it to another color.

```
\setupinteraction
  [state=start,
   color=,
   contrastcolor=,
   style=]

%\enabledirectives[references.border]
\enabledirectives[references.border=green]

\starttext
Here is a \goto{link}[url(http://tex.stackexchange.com)] to my favourite web site.
\stoptext
```

To remove the style of the link you have change the `style` and `color` values with the `\setupinteraction` command.

[image: Framed hyperlink with ConTeXt]