# Optionally colored links in ConTeXt

Tags: color, context, links, ocg

[This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4425/2867) is about having colored links on screen while printing them black. The solution is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{TeX Stackexchange}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

I would like to have the same functionality in ConTeXt. The only commands touching link colors that I know of are:

```
\setupcolors[state=start|stop]
\setupinteraction[state=start|stop,color=...]
```

/edit: The question [ConTeXt: Replace PDF Content During Printing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/466439/2867) provides the building blocks for a solution. Now we only need to find the code that renders links and replace it with `\viewerlayer[view]{\color[#gotocolor]{#text}}\llap{\viewerlayer[print]{#text}}`

Comment: There is no support for coloured links via OCG in ConTeXt.  I guess this is due to the fact that OCG would break PDF/A compatibility.

Comment: @Aditya  This is not a duplicate.  See my edit to the question.

Comment: @HenriMenke Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: @TeXnician No, because my comment is not an answer.

Comment: There's a question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326319/context-hyperlinks/326328#326328) where the answers offer two ways to put coloured boxes **around** links. Not quite what you're asking for, but they're screen-only and don't appear in print.